# Add dynamically loaded UserControls to AvalanDock MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dll, xceed

I have module based application, where each module (.dll) contains one main UserControl. Modules are loaded only when it is necessary and its UserControls are added into a MainWindow. 
The main window is using AvalanDock [2.0] for docking the UserControls of the modules. So far I'm doing it this way:

```
public void DockUserControl(UserControl userControl){
    var documentPane = dockingManager.Layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (documentPane != null)
            var layoutDocument = new LayoutDocument { Content = userControl };
            documentPane.Children.Add(layoutDocument);
            documentPane.SelectedContentIndex = documentPane.Children.IndexOf(layoutDocument);
}
```

This pattern is very limiting, for example I would like to bind a Title of a layoutDocument to the ViewModel of a UserControl, handle the closing events etc.. Therefore I would like to use the MVVM pattern. Typical usage looks as follows:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" 
                           DocumentsSource="{Binding UserControls}">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
        ...
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
        ...
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
...
```

However, there is a lot of modules and the main window should only know that they have some common ancestor. Therefore, I can't list all the UserControls in LayoutItemTemplateSelector. What I have is a list of UserControls.

Do you have any idea, how to use MVVM with dynamically loaded UserControls?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have:

```
public ObservableCollection<EditorViewModel> Documents { get; }
```

In XAML

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}" ....
```

Then I say what is the view of that viewmodel

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.Resources>
            <!-- View with its vm -->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type editor:EditorViewModel}">
                <editor:EditorView />
            </DataTemplate>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.Resources>
```

Finally I put bindings for title and other properties:

```
 <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">  <!-- these properties are in its own vm (EditorViewModel instance)-->
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
            </Style>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
```

In my opinion you could have a basic ViewModel for bindings and then each user control could extend it.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I think that there is the following problem: AvalanDock chooses View based on ViewModel. So if I use general ViewModel for all my UserControls, then AvalanDoock would not be able to decide which View it should choose. More concretely I see the problem in the part where you use <DataTemplate>. Or maybe I need one more hint.

Comment: Maybe you can have a general View, and then put in it your user control, like an iframe or something like that.